# Can't bind 'onchange' event on div inside ul

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, bind, onchange

I have this html:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <div></div>
        Actions
        <div></div>
    </a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>
                <div></div>
                Create New Entry
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <span>Client:<span>
    <select data-filter-name="clients" id="client_filter">
    <option value="0" {if $selectedClient == 0} selected {/if}>All</option>
    {foreach from=$clients key=k item=client}
    <option value="{$k}" {if $selectedClient == $k} selected {/if}>{$client}</option>
    {/foreach}
    </select>
</li>
```

In JS, I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#client_filter').on('change', function(){
        window.location = "/index.php?client_id=" +  $(this).val();
   });
});
```

And event 'onchange' is not attached!
When I click on the select box, nothing happend. Why?
If I place the select box outside  it is working.

Answer (score 1):

you didnt close on change function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#client_filter').on('change', function(){
    window.location = "/index.php?client_id=" +  $(this).val();
})//end change function
})//end ready
```

Comment: it's fine, i just took a snippet of code... It would display an error, I don't get any!

Answer (score 0):

Close your fucntion

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#client_filter').on('change', function(){
        window.location = "/index.php?client_id=" +  $(this).val();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing closing brackets of the event handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#client_filter').on('change', function(){
        window.location = "/index.php?client_id=" +  $(this).val();
    });
});
```